# Служба с графическим интерфейсом

Tags: c#, .net, служба

Возможно ли сделать у службы таймер, который через определенный интервал показывал `MessageBox`? Или в службе никак не сделать сообщения с графическим интерфейсом?

Comment: Где то тут был похожий вопрос. В общем, не сделать

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - на чьем десктопе?

Comment: Для того что бы понять свой же вопрос, прочтите о том что такое служба, и как она должна работать.

Comment: Смотреть функцию `WTSSendMessage`